# c# wpf app, missing .net4.8 framework does not divert to correct web site download

Tags: .net, wpf, runtime, version

I recently wrote a small app in WPF .net targeting the .net 4.8 framework.
It was run on a PC with 4.72 already installed. When the app was run it came up with a prompt dialog stating that 4.8 was missing, with the prompt asking if the user wants to install 4.8 now. If you click yes it takes you to website to install 4.7.2 which is already installed.
Obviously a user can manually find and install 4.8 run time, but how do i determine why the dialog did not got to the correct 4.8 download page.

Is there a setting in visual studio for this ?

Comment: which windows version is installed on the computer?

Comment: windows 10, with all updates to date.

Comment: strange... usually that's something you can't take care of. Windows automatically detects with which version it was compiled and then prompts the user to download the appropriate version of .NET Framework... Probably still an issue on the side of MS

Comment: Are you really using anything that's different to 4.7.2 ?

Comment: I did a comparison in performance in my app between 4.7.2 and 4.8. Definetly runs smoother on 4.8. Don't understand why but it does. So id like to keep it at 4.8